# merge two XML files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XML files with the following format
File 1

```
<info>
  <organization_id>123</organization_id>
  <total_patients>5</total_patients>
</info>
<patients>
  <patient>
    <guid>1111</guid>
   </patient>
  <patient>
    <guid>2222</guid>
   </patient>
</patients>
```

File 2

```
<info>
  <organization_id>456</organization_id>
  <total_patients>10</total_patients>
</info>
<patients>
  <patient>
    <guid>3333</guid>
   </patient>
  <patient>
    <guid>4444</guid>
   </patient>
</patients>
```

I would like to combine the 2 files into one with the following format

Output File

```
<info>
  <total_patients>15</total_patients>
</info>
<organizations>
  <organization>
      <organization_id>123</organization_id>
     <patients>
        <patient>
          <guid>1111</guid>
        </patient>
        <patient>
          <guid>1111</guid>
        </patient>
     </patients>
  </organization>
  <organization>
      <organization_id>456</organization_id>
     <patients>
        <patient>
          <guid>4444</guid>
        </patient>
        <patient>
          <guid>5555</guid>
        </patient>
     </patients>
  </organization>
</organizations>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions. I have been searching Google and could not find anything simmilar to this. Thank you

Comment: You need to be much more specific. What have you tried so far? What is not working for you? Why did you put it in the XSLT category? Because you must use XSLT?

Comment: Your input documents are not well-formed XML. A well formed XML document needs a single root element node.

Comment: What a pity this question was closed (prematurely IMHO). I thought it was a reasonable question and my answer was a good one.

Comment: Seconding Sean's comment - @casperOne's closing of this question is IMHO not only wrong but also offensive. There's nothing "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical" about the question - and it's a top hit on Google.

Comment: @Adam it shows no original research effort. It's a "give me the code" question which is a low quality question on Stack Overflow.  It's also probably a dupe somewhere.

Comment: @casperOne I think you misunderstand what XSLT problems are like - perhaps it's a side effect of XSLT lackin a debugger, but ... In pratice, XSLT is almost impossible to ask about without a simple concrete specific problem. The solution is almost always generic - and extremely useful for anyone else with an XSLT with similar structure (which is very very common). You may not like the question, but as XSLT questions go it's very solid - and almost identical to most of the other XSLT questions on SO *while being a clearly unique problem* (I've read many others, none were dupes)

Answer (score 4):

Making a couple of adjustments so that your input and expected output becomes well formed, I suggest the following XSLT 2.0 solution. The adjustments are:

1. Enclose each input documents into single  nodes.
2. Enclose the expected output document into a single  node.

So, to transform the following document ....

```
<organization>
 <info>
  <organization_id>123</organization_id>
  <total_patients>5</total_patients>
 </info>
 <patients>
  <patient>
    <guid>1111</guid>
   </patient>
  <patient>
    <guid>2222</guid>
   </patient>
 </patients>
</organization>
```

Include the following co-input document ...

```
<organization>
 <info>
  <organization_id>456</organization_id>
  <total_patients>10</total_patients>
 </info>
 <patients>
  <patient>
    <guid>3333</guid>
   </patient>
  <patient>
    <guid>4444</guid>
   </patient>
 </patients>
</organization>
```

... which will be referenced, in your invocation of the XSLT engine as parameter with name "org2", applying the following XSLT2 transformation ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  version="2.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn">

<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:param name="org2" />
<xsl:variable name="org2-doc" select="document($org2)" />

<xsl:template  match="/">
 <output>
  <info>
   <total_patients>
    <xsl:number value="organization/info/total_patients +
             $org2-doc/organization/info/total_patients" />
   </total_patients>
  </info>
   <organizations>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$org2-doc/*" />
   </organizations>
 </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template  match="organization">
  <organization>
   <organization_id>
    <xsl:number value="info/organization_id" />
   </organization_id>
   <xsl:copy-of select="patients" />   
  </organization>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... produces the desired result ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <info>
      <total_patients>15</total_patients>
   </info>
   <organizations>
    <organization>
       <organization_id>123</organization_id>
       <patients>
          <patient>
             <guid>1111</guid>
          </patient>
          <patient>
             <guid>2222</guid>
          </patient>
       </patients>
    </organization>
    <organization>
       <organization_id>456</organization_id>
       <patients>
          <patient>
             <guid>3333</guid>
          </patient>
          <patient>
             <guid>4444</guid>
          </patient>
       </patients>
    </organization>
   </organizations>
</output>
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. It's been ages since I've had to merge 2 XML files in this complex fashion, and I was racking my head for the cleanest way. The top-level param/variable approach is just what I was trying to remember.

Answer (score 2):

Use an XML DOM parser in any language you're comfortable with.
Parse both files, extract organization IDs.
Create a new DOM tree, a new `<info>` node, a new `<organizations>` node. For each organization, copy `<patients>` nodes under corresponding organization nodes.
Serialize the resulting XML.

(If you're so inclined, you could try XSLT, but this path, while possibly shorter, may feel somehow masochistic.)

No, I'm too lazy to actually write working code for you.